# When to use a filter vs a directive in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's a simple question - and it may have been asked (just couldn't find it..)

When would you use a filter over a directive when it comes to manipulating the data, or vice versa?

In a really really simple example, see this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RMh2mcB49WDsmBemsQrU?p=preview)

Essentially, I have the following `javascript`

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.testMessage = 'Some Text'
}]);

app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{ 
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            // do some stuff with the data
            // 
            element.html(scope.testMessage + ' result of my directive');
        }
    }
});

app.filter('myFilter', function(){
    return function(text){
     // do something with text
        return text + ' & result of my filter';
    }
});
```

And the following `html`

```
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div my-directive ng-model="testMessage" ></div>
    <br />
    <div>{{ testMessage | myFilter }}</div>
  </body>
```

So when would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some hints (non-exhaustive lists):

### Directive

Use it when...

- You want to do structural manipulation of the DOM
- You want to add behaviour (the controller)
- The outcome is dependent on other collaborators (the `require` configuration of the directive)

### Filter

Use it when...

- You are transforming a value to another (e.g. String → Date)
- (Subset of the above, but important to warrant it's own bullet:) When you are transforming an array (e.g. to be displayed in repeated elements - the `filter` filter and `ng-repeat`)

Answer (score 10):

#### Clear and simple

Filter for general **Data** filtering / transformation

Directive for **DOM** Manipulation / **UI** behavior

---

In your case you can write it like so:

```
  <div>{{ testMessage + ' result' }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One more point I want to add apart from

1. Filter for general Data filtering / transformation
2. Directive for DOM Manipulation / UI behavior

Generally we use filters for an array of data.

I feel like there is no logical difference between them. Both does the same job.
It is usage which is different.