# Custom html for currency -- filter or directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ionic-framework, directive

I've been given a UX design that displays the currency symbol as Gray and the decimal value as black.  To implement this, I did some Googling and ended up making a simple filter:

```
.filter('tnCurrency', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, symbol, decimal) {
        var amt = $filter('currency')(input, '', decimal);

        return  '<span class="tn-currency-symbol">' + symbol + '</span><span class="tn-currency-amt">' + amt + '</span>';       
    };
}]);
```

Usage:

```
<span ng-bind-html="total.amt | tnCurrency:'$':2"></span>
```

I've been thinking about it for a while...should this be better implemented as a directive or should I stick with filter?

Answer (score 1):

A directive is more appropriate when manipulating the DOM, while a filter is more suited for transforming the value.

I'd create a directive that uses the currency filter.

Here's a good thread on [when to use a directive vs when to use a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975106/when-to-use-a-filter-vs-a-directive-in-angularjs).